# How to increase the heap size of the google cloud app engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, heap-memory

I am now using *Google Cloud App Engine Standard environment* for Java application and I am getting `outOfMemory Error` cause the Java heap size` is quite filled.

I know why cause I'm processing a lot of data which might reach 1GB. So how do I increase the heap size allocated for a java app running in App Engine Standard environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed my problem by moving to java8 and now Im using java 8 environmental variables to increase the java heap size by adding this to the appengine-web.xml

```
   <env-variables>       
        <env-var name="GAE_MEMORY_MB" value="1024M" />
        <env-var name="HEAP_SIZE_RATIO" value="90" />
    </env-variables>
```

Comment: Do you know anything about why this worked? I would have thought the memory is limited by the instance class. Maybe the `HEAP_SIZE_RATIO` is important. it looks like the default ratio is 80%.

Answer (score 2):

By default App Engine Standard use the F instances which only has 128MB and 600MHz processors. We had the same heap issues and we ended up "upgrading" to more powerful App Engine Standard instances. You can also switch to auto-scaling basic or manual which will give you more control over your requests (requests no longer timeout in 10 minutes for example). More info about the different Instance classes can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/)
In order to apply the change you will have to update your [appengine-web.xml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref#scaling_elements_automatic_scaling) and add the following:

```
<instance-class>B4</instance-class>
<basic-scaling>
  <idle-timeout>60m</idle-timeout>
  <max-instances>10</max-instances>
</basic-scaling>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's possible to use Cloud Storage or Datastore to offload some of the data, you should consider using Kubernetes or Compute engine as they allow more fine tuning and have [more options](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types) to choose from compared to [GAE](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/#instance_classes).

Comment: Im thinking of moving to java8 and use java 8 environmental variables to increase the heap size, as mentioned in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/dev-java-only#variables)

Comment: As per [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/), "VM instances in the flexible environment are Google Compute Engine virtual machines", so what you propose might indeed be a suitable option for you, as App Engine Standard applications have a maximum of 1GB of memory. In [this other documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types) there is a  list of available Compute Engine instances.