# Java App on Standard GAE randomly get out of space. How to set up Heap?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, heap-memory

How can I manage the value of heap size for a java app on AppEngine in the standard version?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to increase the heap size of the google cloud app engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48314063/how-to-increase-the-heap-size-of-the-google-cloud-app-engine)